# Live Feed from raspicam on canvas covering everything even cursor

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, canvas, raspberry-pi

I am working on an app that basically turns the raspberry pi 4 into a camera, since I've been learning opencv i thought it would be a cool way to show off everything that I've done so far,

I do manage to retrieve the feed of the raspicam, but it's on the top layer so it covers up everything, including my cursor and i can't even stop the app.

I retrieve the image with this code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  camera_pi.py
#
#
#
import time
import io
import threading
import picamera


class Camera(object):
    thread = None  # background thread that reads frames from camera
    frame = None  # current frame is stored here by background thread
    last_access = 0  # time of last client access to the camera

    def initialize(self):
        if Camera.thread is None:
            # start background frame thread
            Camera.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._thread)
            Camera.thread.start()

            # wait until frames start to be available
            while self.frame is None:
                time.sleep(0)

    def get_frame(self):
        Camera.last_access = time.time()
        self.initialize()
        return self.frame

    @classmethod
    def _thread(cls):
        with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
            # camera setup
            camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
            camera.hflip = True
            camera.vflip = True
            #camera.zoom = (0.22,0,0.7,0.7) # (x, y, w, h)

            # let camera warm up
            camera.start_preview()
            time.sleep(2)

            stream = io.BytesIO()
            for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg',
                                                 use_video_port=True):
                # store frame
                stream.seek(0)
                cls.frame = stream.read()

                # reset stream for next frame
                stream.seek(0)
                stream.truncate()

                # if there hasn't been any clients asking for frames in
                # the last 10 seconds stop the thread
                #if time.time() - cls.last_access > 10:
                    #break
        cls.thread = None
```

And then make it into a full screen Tkinter widget with this code:

```
import cv2
from camera_pi import *
import sys, os
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:  # the tkinter library changed it's name from Python 2 to 3.
    import Tkinter
    tkinter = Tkinter #I decided to use a library reference to avoid potential naming conflicts with people's programs.
else:
    import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time



camera = Camera()

feed = camera.get_frame()
   
frame =  cv2.imread(feed)

#cv2.imshow(frame)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()

root = tkinter.Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
root.focus_set()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root,width=w,height=h)
canvas.pack()
canvas.configure(background='black')
  
SetButton = Button(root,text="Settings", command=root.destroy)
SetButton.place(x=0,y=0)


def showPIL(pilImage):
    imgWidth, imgHeight = pilImage.size
 # resize photo to full screen 
    ratio = min(w/imgWidth, h/imgHeight)
    imgWidth = int(imgWidth*ratio)
    imgHeight = int(imgHeight*ratio)
    pilImage = pilImage.resize((imgWidth,imgHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)   
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
    imagesprite = canvas.create_image(w/2,h/2,image=image)
    imagesprite.lower()
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
    root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: (e.widget.withdraw(), e.widget.quit()))

try:
    showPIL(frame)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    root.destroy
```

I'd like to add a button on the corner to open up a settings window where i could modify the camera parameters, or start one of the opencv modes ive been working on but being that i can't see the cursor that doesn't work, i also tried to use the canvas function to lower, and tried moving it around in the code but i think its because the image keeps refreshing, or i simply did it wrong.

Comment: For the raspberry pi you might consider using [here](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/) for help catering to your specific problem.  I only mention it because without a raspberry pi it is hard for someone to recreate this issue. I'm not saying there aren't people here that can help, just wanted to point you to another resource.

Comment: please focus your question. review [ask] and [mre]. if your issue is with a Tkinter window being too big, say so. if the issue is with OpenCV's imshow() window being too big, say so. pick one.

Comment: You couldn't, extract all. It is better from camera_pi import Camera

Comment: You need this from picamera.array import PiRGBArray